# Approximating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-f(q)/\hbar} dq$

Tags: mathematical-physics, linear-approximation, approximate-integration

I'm a Physics student (self-studying Zee's *Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell*) hoping to get the following mathematical query solved.

It is mentioned that to approximate $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-f(q)/\hbar} dq$, where $f$ is a real-valued function, the maximum contribution is from the minimum of $f$ for small $\hbar$. Assuming that $f$ has a (local as well as global) minimum at $q=a$, we expand $f$ around $q=a$ as $f(q) = f(a)+{1\over 2}f''(q-a)^2+O((q-a)^3)$ and then exploit the known Gaussian integral to get $$I\approx e^{-f(a)/\hbar}\Biggl({2\pi\hbar\over f''(a)}\Biggr)^{1/2}e^{-O(h^{1/2})}.$$

**Question:** What I don't understand is the origin of the term $e^{-O(h^{1/2})}$. Can you help?

Comment: Keep the $O((q-a)^3)$ term in the derivation, i.e. when you do the change of variables to get it on the form of a normal gaussian integral do it also to this term.

Comment: @Winther I tried that, but couldn’t make any progress...

Comment: To  solve the integral you would put $u = \sqrt{f''(a)/2h}(q-a)$ right (to get $e^{-u^2}$). Now what is $(q-a)^3/h$ in terms of $u$ and $h$?

Comment: @Winther That solved it! Thanks! I was just plugging and chugging in the formula from the table.